# how to use system environment variables in boto

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto

I have exported AWS ACCESS KEY and SECRET via the environment variables, is there way to use those variables in the boto script instead of writing them to a file on the system?
I don't want to write the key and secret in any file on the remote server.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If by *use* you mean read them and feed them into boto: You don't need to do that. Boto reads them, and in all calls which would usually expect the `aws_access_key_id=` and `aws_secret_access_key=` parameters, you just leave them out altogether. Hence a call like this would work without problems:

```
# note that we don't pass any credentials here...

conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region("eu-west-1")
```

Just be sure the environment variables are set correctly. These are the correct names to use:

`AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`

More details here:
http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/boto_config_tut.html#introduction

Comment: Thanks that works I tried it, but looks like we have issues when I use the boto script in cron job.

Comment: @user3435964 Cron doesn't read environment variables, because they are part of shell profiles. (It only sets some rudimentary ones like ``HOME``) You can set them right at the beginning of the crontab file, though. Just assign them with ``AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=...`` and ``AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=...`` before the schedules are defined.

Answer (score 5):

Boto looks for the environment variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and, if they are present in the environment, it will use them.